# How do I access a progress bar in a main-activity containing a tabhost from one of the tabs?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am developing an android application where I have a main-activity that contains a progress bar and a tabhost. the tabhost has 3 tabs.

How do I from a tab-activity access the progress bar in the main activity? I want to be able to start and stop the progress bar when things changes inside each tab ativity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways:

1. Couple the classes together: create a custom Application and save a weak reference to ProgressBar to a field. Use `getApplication()` inside tab activities and cast it to your custom Application.
   Note: Use weak reference inside your Application class to [prevent memory leaks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).
2. Create your own `Broadcast` and `BroadcastReceiver`, where tab activities send broadcasts and progress bar listens to them: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#broadcastreceivers
3. Read how to [pass data between Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html#3).

Answer (score 1):

use getParent() in each tab-Activity